# Patent Application Size

Tags: patent-applications, provisional-application

If I am searching for a patent agent to review a patent application, I would expect that the agent would want to understand the size / complexity of the work.

How is this typically ballparked?  For example:

- page count of the drawings and
- a page count non-drawings (reading material)
- number of claims + page count of claims

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered, since I don't think there is a typical approach. I suspect you would be best off asking your prospective attorney.

Comment: I don't think the complexity can be measured with pages. They'll probably tell you how many hours it took when they bill you ;)

Comment: I would want to take a quick look at it and then charge a small fixed fee to discuss the result you are expecting to get out of the exercise. In my experience it would be a rare occurrence that a patent practitioner would take on a detailed review of an inventor's draft application. The likelihood that it was close enough to what would be worth filing to be reviewable is usually  low.

Comment: I would say that it is more that you say a price and ask if they can complete within that budget. You get what you pay for though...

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but my guess is that a patent attorney or agent would want to draft the entire patent and claims. Now the fact that you wrote your own draft should make this process more efficient, but I'm assuming that it is unlikely your draft would be adequate in the eyes of the agent.

Comment: you get what you pay for will not apply in the service industry, it will apply to products only. You can get good patent applications written at an affordable price. You can not judge quality based on what you have paid.

Comment: complexity can not be estimated based on page count, it depends on the technology involved. Usually, Inventors can not write better patent applications and it takes a lot of time to correct application. It is better to start fresh by an attorney than correcting.

Answer (score 1):

I just spoke to an attorney about reviewing my pro se patent application. He told me that if an attorney reviews my application it must legally be done as a client. In the case of reviewing my application as my attorney he makes recommendations to changes and I then submit my application after making said changes it no longer technically is pro se. If the USPTO discovers this the helping attorney can be possibly disbarred. 
He told me good luck on finding an attorney that is willing to risk their license.

Comment: I'm a patent agent, subject to the exact same rights and responsibilities - relative to the USPTO - as a patent attorney. I agree with the "good luck finding an attorney" to review your application but there is no USPTO rule that it cannot be done.  If you did engage someone to review your application you would automatically be considered a client. When I started out I reviewed a couple of inventor-written applications - It's not likely to end well. A lawyer's insurance might not allow him/her to take on this type engagement, but it would not be an ethical violation of the USPTO ethics rules.

Comment: Thank you for your time in adding to my comment. I was very excited several days ago when I began searching for an attorney that may be willing to review my claims. The first attorney that I spoke with is the one who provided the information I supplid in my answer. Your comment has reinvigorated my desire to continue my searching. I understand the results more than likely will  be futile so I will devote less time than originally scheduled in my search.